# How do I trigger code to run when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom of a table view in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using CloudKit to populate the data source of a table view in iOS using Swift. I would like to trigger code to run when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom of the table view to fetch more data to add to the data source. Is there a built in way that UITableView can trigger code at such a time or would I need to use my own implementation for this?

Comment: @rmaddy Should I delete this question?

Comment: That's up to you. Duplicates aren't necessarily bad since it allows more searches to lead to the answer.